# Does MSN Messenger now use SSL communication out of the box?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I'm using the latest version of msn messenger, and I communicate with friends who use Pidgin client on Linux.

Is the transport text ssl encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. MSN messenger doesn't encrypt anything, except, maybe, login information. You could use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) if you're concerned with the security of your local area network.